# Recursive Set method in Java - Default variable a la Perl?

Tags: java, oop

The only other language I've any experience with is Perl & this is my first crack at OO programming.  I feel like I'm approaching this all wrong.  One of the problems is probably me trying to code OO Java like I coded non-OO Perl.  Can anyone suggest a way to gracefully accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish in the code snippet below?

Note: The ??? in my code is where I would want to use the default object.

```
public class Var {
    private double var1;

    public Var (double PassedVar1) {  //method to create new object
        var1 = ???.SetVar1(PassedVar1);
    }

    public void SetVar1 (double PassedVar) {
        if (PassedVar > 0) {  //make sure we're assigning a positive value
            var1 = PassedVar;
        }
        else {  //force user to input a new value
            System.out.print( "\nFailed to set var.  " +
            "Please enter a number greater than zero: ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            PassedVar = scan.nextDouble();
            var1 = ???.SetVar1(PassedVar);//recurse call to assure positive
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The word you're looking for is `this` (i.e. `this.SetVar1(...)`), however in Java that's not necessary. You can just use `SetVar1(...)` in any non-static member of `Var` of any subclasses of `Var`.

No doubt others will offer advice on a better way to accomplish your task in Java, so I won't answer that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would become this, after a little refactoring and fixing,

```
public class Var {
    private double var1;

    public Var (double passedVar1) {  //method to create new object
        setVar1(passedVar1); // You just need to invoke setVar1() by passing the argument
    }

    public void setVar1 (double passedVar1) {
        if (passedVar1 > 0) {  //make sure we're assigning a positive value
            var1 = passedVar1;
        } else {  //force user to input a new value
            System.out.print( "\nFailed to set var.  " +
                                   "Please enter a number greater than zero: ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            passedVar1 = scan.nextDouble();
            setVar1(passedVar1); //recurse call to assure positive
        }
    }
}
```

**Okay because of critics, I dare to change it drastically.**

```
public class Var {

    private double var1;

    private Var(double var1) { 
        this.var1 = var1;
    } 

    public static final Var getVar(double var1) { 
        return (var1 > 0) ? new Var(var1) : null;
    }    
}
```

In this way the calling code should check for `null` and do whatever it likes to on encountering `null`. Anyways, below is the code snippet that is making sure that the input `double` is valid and then instantiating `Var`.

```
         ...
         double passedVar1 = 0D;
         do {
            System.out.print( "\nFailed to set var.  " +
                                   "Please enter a number greater than zero: ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            passedVar1 = scan.nextDouble();
         } while (passedVar1 < 0)

         Var var = Var.getVar(passedVar1);
         ...
```

Cheers.

Comment: I would use a `while` loop instead of a recursive call to `setVar1` so that a huge series of bad inputs doesn't cause a StackOverflow.

Comment: I would provide a no-args constructor which calls this(-1) as well. This will mean that you can create a Var easily and the user will be prompted for the input.

Comment: @Gabe: Of course, I am assuming that the main reason to write the recursive code is for the sake of writing recursion. It looks like an assignment kind of thing to me. Thats the reason, I didn't change it much.

Comment: @Syntax: Then it would be completely different thing, when you are able to create the `Var` instance. And BTW, how the user will be prompted for the input?